# how to save intent data passed from 1st activity to 2nd activity

Tags: android, database, android-intent, sharedpreferences, android-sqlite

I have Myactivity which is getting the intent data from the former activity. The intent data is sent through a spinner of the activity. I want to save this intent data of the spinner to the Myactvity. the intent data should persist when i enter the Myactivity through menu option of next activity.

Answer (score 3):

in your First Activity1

```
Intent myintent= new Intent(FirstActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
myintent.putExtra("Name", "your String");
startActivity(myintent);
```

in Second Activity2

```
Intent myintent = getIntent();

if(null!=myintent.getExtras()){
    String Name= myintent.getExtras().getString("Name");        
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),""+Name,12).show();                              
}else{
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"No Recor Here..",12).show();
}
```

like SharedPreferences[2]
in your First ActivityA

```
Intent myintent= new Intent(FirstActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
SharedPreferences spref = this.getSharedPreferences("mynotifyid", MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);
SharedPreferences.Editor spreedit = spref.edit();
spreedit.putString("Name1", str1.toString());   
spreedit.putString("Name2", str2.toString());   
spreedit.putString("Name3", str3.toString());   
spreedit.putString("Name4", str4.toString());   
spreedit.commit();
startActivity(myintent);
```

in your Second ActivityB

```
SharedPreferences spref = context.getSharedPreferences("mynotifyid", Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);
String str1 = spref.getString("Name1","");
String str2 = spref.getString("Name2","");
String str3 = spref.getString("Name3","");
String str4 = spref.getString("Name4","");
```

for your object saving purpose use SharedPreferences

Comment: Can the code make use of sharedpreference? Instead of toast how to make use of sharedpreference for persisting the intent data?