# android listview via soap calling

Tags: android, parsing, android-listview, listadapter, android-ksoap2

i have developed android listview via soap calling is successfully..now i have to click any item from that list means the detail description is displayed...

this is my sample listview format:

```
1 F
2 Q
3 P
```

here i need to click the 1 F item means the F is display on next activity.samething i have to click 2 Q means the Q is display on next activity.

Next activity have to Like this :(click 1 F means it is go to next activity and display F)

```
F
```

how can i develop this.please help me...

Here i have to click the 1 F means it is go to next activity...nothing is displayed on next activity.

This is my code:

```
public class RetailerActivity extends Activity {
ListView list;
private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://xcart.com/customerData1";
private static final String METHOD_NAME = "customerData1";
private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://xcart.com";
private static final String URL = "http://192.168.1.168:8089/XcartLogin/services/RetailerWs?wsdl";
private static final String KEY_STATUS = "status";



/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME); 

    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

    HttpTransportSE ht = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
    try {
        ht.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
        SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
        SoapPrimitive s = response;
        String str = s.toString();
        String resultArr[] = str.split("&");
        list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);


        list.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,resultArr));
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {


                String status = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.status)).getText().toString();

                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SingleMenuItemActivity.class);
                in.putExtra(KEY_STATUS, status);
                startActivity(in);                  

            }
        });     
    }


    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```

This is another activity:

```
 public class SingleMenuItemActivity  extends Activity {

// XML node keys
static final String KEY_STATUS = "status";

@Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.single_list_item);

    Intent in = getIntent();
    String status = in.getStringExtra(KEY_STATUS);


    // Displaying all values on the screen
    TextView lblName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.status_label);
    lblName.setText(status);

}
}
```

This is single_list_item.xml file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<!-- Name Label -->
 <TextView android:id="@+id/status_label"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="25dip"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:paddingTop="10dip"
        android:paddingBottom="10dip"
        android:textColor="#dc6800"
       />

 </LinearLayout>
```

please help me..how can i develop this.

Comment: refer this link....[android-listview-using-soap-calling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12472041/android-listview-using-soap-calling)

Comment: that also my question only.....this is my another question....both are different question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here i think onItemClick you not getting value  so get values like

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {    
        @Override
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

         String status =  parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
         String[] status1  = status.split(" ");
         String StrStatus = status1[1].toString();

            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SingleMenuItemActivity.class);
            in.putExtra(KEY_STATUS, StrStatus );
            startActivity(in);                  

        }
    });
```

for more value passing ActivityA to B and get value see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12426045/how-to-save-intent-data-passed-from-1st-activity-to-2nd-activity/12426139#12426139) this may helps you

Comment: you can splite your String with space and get it

Comment: i have  change it with split option check now

Comment: when you click then try to debug or toast make sure you getting values

Comment: in next Activity you missing if(null!=myintent.getExtras())

Comment: you make splite String and then pass in Intent ?

Comment: still you not change in Next Activity with myintent.getExtras()